# Why Firebase query with orderByChild returns a link?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data), I use this code to get the players in ascending order:

```js
 const db = getDatabase();
 const playersByPoints = query(
      ref(db, 'usersPoints'),
      orderByChild('points'),
    );
```

But when I `console.log(playersByPoints)` I get this:

`"https://app-name.firebaseio.com/usersPoints"`

Here is the database:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `playersByPoints` here is a `Query` object, which when logged returns the string of the linked database reference.

You need to actually invoke the query using either [`get(q)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#get) or [`onValue(q)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#onvalue) to get the data you are looking for.

```js
// one-off
const playersByPointsQuery = query(
  ref(db, 'usersPoints'),
  orderByChild('points'),
);

const playersByPointsQuerySnapshot = await get(playersByPointsQuery);
const playersByPoints = [];
      
playersByPointsQuerySnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  playersByPoints.push({
    ...childSnapshot.val(),
    _key: childSnapshot.key
  });
});

// todo: do something with playersByPoints
```

or

```js
// realtime listener
const playersByPointsQuery = query(
  ref(db, 'usersPoints'),
  orderByChild('points'),
);

const unsubscribe = onValue(
  playersByPointsQuery,
  {
    next: (playersByPointsQuerySnapshot) => {
      // new data available
      const playersByPoints = [];
      
      playersByPointsQuerySnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        playersByPoints.push({
          ...childSnapshot.val(),
          _key: childSnapshot.key
        });
      });
    
      // todo: do something with playersByPoints
    },
    error: (err) => {
      // error
      // todo: handle
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi @samthecodingman! The first option works, but I get this error: `Error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "points", for path "/usersPoints", to the rules` Could you elaborate on solving this! Thanks!

Comment: I had rules like this: `  "usersPoints": {
       ".read": true,
        "$userID": {
        ".write": "$userID === auth.uid"
      }
    },` and I changed it to this: `   "usersPoints": {
       ".read": true,
       ".write": true
    },`. But the error insists!

Comment: It's OK I got it. I just added `".indexOn": "points"` under `"usersPoints": { ...`